# Filter a deeply nested object in c# using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, filter, lambda

How do you filter a deeply nested object in c# using lambda expressions?

## Example object:

```
Object A (A1)
    | Object B (B1)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = X
        | Object C (C2)
            | Field = Y
        | Object C (C3)
            | Field = Z
    | Object B (B2)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = X
    | Object B (B3)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = Y
    | Object B (B4)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = X
        | Object C (C2)
            | Field = Z
    | Object B (B5)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = Y
        | Object C (C2)
            | Field = Z
Object A (A2)
    | Object B (B1)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = X
        | Object C (C2)
            | Field = Z
    | Object B (B2)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = Y
```

If I wanted to filter Object C on Field = X, I would expect the following results:

```
Object A (A1)
    | Object B (B1)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = X
    | Object B (B2)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = X
    | Object B (B3)
    | Object B (B4)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = X
    | Object B (B5)
Object A (A2)
    | Object B (B1)
        | Object C (C1)
            | Field = X
    | Object B (B2)
```

Is there a way to write a single Lambda expression in c# in order to accomplish this?

The solutions I have found through my searches do something like this, which filters Object A instead of Object C:

```
query.Where(a => a.ObjectB.Any(b => b.ObjectC.Any(c => c.Field == X)))
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] with corresponding classes/entities provided. Also are you writing some ORM query (like for EF Core) or this is LINQ to Objects?

Comment: query.SelectMany(a => a.ObjectB.SelectMany(b => b.ObjectC)).Where(c => c.Field == X)

Comment: @YevhenCherkes That won't work when you want to return the original `A` list of objects.

Comment: To change the collection (?) of C's in each B, you will have to create new B's which would mean creating new A's or modify the existing B's to delete the items you don't want or modify the existing A's to have the new B's. C# is a language of types - showing your actual types is essential. You could also create a new wrapper class around a collection of A's that filter the view of the C's.

Comment: In my particular scenario we pull the List<ObjectA> from EF (.Net 4.7) and store it in a static variable called query.  ObjectA contains a List<ObjectB>, and ObjectB contains a List<ObjectC>, which contains many fields, but I just want to filter on one of them.  I don't want to add/remove values from the query since it is static and we run many different filters against the data.  I was hoping there was a way to filter ObjectB to only return ObjectC's with a certain value (X in the example).

Comment: If you are using `Include`, then unfortunately EF doesn't filtered `Include` until recent EF Core, so the best you could do is not eager load the related `ObjectC` but run a separate query to load them in the context.